# Caroufredsel prev/next not working in firefox

Tags: firefox, caroufredsel

works perfectly in chrome and safari, but take users to the top of the page on firefox

this is the config script in the header:

```
$("#bottle-carousel1").carouFredSel({
    auto: false,
    prev: "#prev1 > a.prev",
    next: "#next1 > a.next",
    mousewheel: false,
});
```

these are the links themselves:

```
<div id="prev1"><a class="prev" href="">prev</a></div>
<div id="next1"><a class="next" href="">next</a></div>
```

the code is working fine, just not in firefox and not clear why. most folks posting with problems are saying that it works in firefox but not chrome or safari, this is not the case for me.

Comment: http://mesabev.zencloud.me/ this is the dev link, but will be gone shortly.

Comment: check if firebug show any JS error.

Comment: thanks, but there are no errors, it works perfectly in other browsers. firebug shows no errors.

Comment: that doesn't make sense, if you can put some code jsfiddle.com could be better

Comment: you can see it working here: mesabev.zencloud.me - may add it to jsfiddle later, but got a bunch of other stuff to do now. i really appreciate your assistance though

Comment: found the problem: i had added 'event.preventDefault()' as chrome gave me an warning saying 'event.returnValue' was deprecated so i had preventDefault to the end of the script to clean up the warning. once i removed that firefox was working fine, so now i get a warning in chrome, but it works in all browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I can't replicate the problem, it works fine on my FF, but if I had to take a guess I would say the problem is the `<a>` tag with no href value. The browser's default value might just be to reload or return to the top of the page (like how it does when # is used.)

I would try removing the `<a>` tag altogether, as you don't really need it.

the markup would become:

```
<div id="prev1">prev</div>
<div id="next1">next</div>
```

and the JS would be:

```
$("#bottle-carousel1").carouFredSel({
    auto: false,
    prev: "#prev1",
    next: "#next1",
    mousewheel: false,
});
```

then in your css just make sure you have:

```
#prev1,
#next1 {
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

so that it looks the same

Comment: thanks for your time, but i found the issue:  
 i had added 'event.preventDefault()' as chrome gave me an warning saying 'event.returnValue' was deprecated so i had preventDefault to the end of the script to clean up the warning. once i removed that firefox was working fine, so now i get a warning in chrome, but it works in all browsers. –

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to download original version of carouFredSel?
I had the same issue with a bootstrap them. 
I replaced this file with online (theme) version jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1-packed.js

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Would you mind extending the answer little bit more to explain how it solves the problem.